# How to produce an A4-format pdf of a man page?

Tags: macos, command-line

I know that `man -t ls | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app` produce a pdf of the man page of the `ls` command.

But the pdf produced is in US Letter size (21.59 cm x 27.94 cm).

The man page of `man` says that `-t` option use internally `/usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc -c`.

So, according the `groff` man, I tried this for obtaining A4 size (21 cm x 29.7 cm) in the pdf (A4 size is widely used in Europe):

`man -t ls | /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc -c  -P-pa4 | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app`.

I obtain the A4 size as desired, but the formatting is ugly (no bold, italic, characters doubled, underscored)...

How to have the good formatting (as in the first command) AND the right size (as in the later command)?

### Update (February 2024)

Apple has dropped the support of the PostScript format, internally used by `man -t`, with macOS Sonoma (macOS 14). See https://eclecticlight.co/2023/09/25/postscripts-sudden-death-in-sonoma/.

So `man -t ls | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app` don't work on macOS Sonoma and after. But in comment, Gilby provide a working alternative.

Below is a proof that `man -t` create a PostScript file.

With `man -t groff > groff.txt`, the output of `man -t groff` is sent to a new file, created with the name `groff.txt`. The first lines of this file contains:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%Orientation: Portrait
```

We recognise at beginning the *magic number* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#In_files) of a PostScript file.

Comment: Doesn't it "just work" using mandoc?

Comment: @Gilby Thanks a lot. So the straight solution is: `mandoc -T pdf -O paper=a4 $(man -w ls) > man-ls.pdf` (`man -w ls` is for obtaining the path to the **ls** man file). If you write a answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of macOS 14 Sonoma, `mandoc` can directly create A4 output, though the default is US Letter. All that is needed is:

`mandoc -T pdf -O paper=a4 $(man -w ls) > man-ls.pdf`

Regarding paper size `man mandoc` says:

```
paper=name
The paper size name may be one of a3, a4, a5, legal, or letter. You may also manually
specify dimensions as NNxNN, width by height in millimetres. If an unknown value is
encountered, letter is used.
```

To simplify viewing `man` pages, I use the function `pman` defined in my `.zshrc` as:

`function pman() { mandoc -T pdf -O paper=a4 "$(man -w $@)" | open -fa Preview }`

Comment: Works like a charm !

Answer (score 8):

Right now you are running groff twice, once as part of `man -t`, once on it‘s own on the PostScript file generated by `man`.

Try

```
groff -Tps -mandoc -c -P-pa4 /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1 >out.ps
ps2pdf out.ps man-ls.pdf
open man-ls.pdf
```

or directly

```
groff -Tps -mandoc -c -P-pa4 /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1 | 
    open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

---

To have it work for all man pages accessible to man, a little script will help.

```
#!/bin/sh
page=$(man -W $1)
if [ -r "$page" ]; then
    groff -Tps -mandoc -c -P-pa4 "$page" | open -f -a Preview.app
fi
```

Save it as `manA4`, run `chmod +x manA4` once, and then use it as `manA4 ls`.

---

In case you are working with compressed man pages (which macOS does *not* use by default) you need to uncompress them on the fly.

```
#!/bin/bash
page=$(man -W $1)
if [ -r "$page" ]; then
    if [[ "$page" =~ .*.gz$ ]]; then
        gzcat "$page" | groff -Tps -mandoc -c -P-pa4 | open -f -a Preview.app
    else
        groff -Tps -mandoc -c -P-pa4 "$page" | open -f -a Preview.app
    fi
fi
```

Comment: This solution does not work with compressed man pages.

Comment: @fd0 I felt tempted to leave this as an exercise to the reader (especially because macOS doesn't work with compressed man pages by default) :-)

Comment: True, but in `man.conf`, `/usr/local/share/man` is mapped which may have compressed man pages.

Comment: Is `ps2pdf` a command? I do a `man ps2pdf` and also enter `ps2pdf` at a prompt and get error messages.

Comment: @DavidAnderson maybe I installed it through Homebrew or as part of TeX. But it‘s not required anyway, Preview can read and render Postscript files directly.

Answer (score 3):

Edit /private/etc/man.conf by commenting out the line

```
TROFF       /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc -c
```

then add this line

```
TROFF       /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc -c -P-pa4
```

Now `man -t` will write ps files in A4 paper size.

```
man -t ls | open .......
```

Comment: And don't forget to repeat this after every macOS upgrade...