# Can man pages be converted to html and/or pdf format?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, pdf, html

The command `man bash` produces a lot of output. What I desire would be to either search the results or print the results to paper. So, is there a way to convert a man page to a html and/or pdf document.

I would prefer the answer work for not only `man bash`, but rather for any man page.

I know the output from `man bash` has been posted on the internet, but usually these posts are not current.

Comment: A Mac specific solution for PDF is discussed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303737/how-to-produce-an-a4-format-pdf-of-an-man-page

Comment: @Ture: How do enter the `ps2pdf` command? Is the command hiding somewhere?

Comment: If you're happy with US letter format and an interactive workflow, you don't need ps2pdf; just run `man -t ls | open -f -a Preview` and then save as PDF from Preview. Otherwise, ps2pdf comes as part of the Ghostscript package which, I believe, is most easily installed via Homebrew.

Comment: For a convenient way to browse PDFs of man pages in your browser, you can use [Bwana](http://www.bruji.com/bwana/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there are [numerous tools to convert manual pages](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=man+page+to+html) to HTML and PDF.

## UNIX Approach

[Converting a man page to HTML, PDF, and text](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/man-to-html-txt-pdf.php) provides detailed instructions for macOS:

```
cat /usr/share/man/man1/osascript.1 | groff -mandoc -Thtml >man_osascript.html
```

If the file ends in `.gz`, then substitute the following.

```
gunzip --to-stdout /usr/share/man/man8/cupsfilter.8.gz | groff -mandoc -Thtml >man_cupsfilter.html
```

For converting from HTML to PDF:

```
cupsfilter man_osascript.html > man_osascript.pdf
```

For other tool chains, see these related questions:

- [How do I convert Linux man pages to HTML without using groff?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246888/how-do-i-convert-linux-man-pages-to-html-without-using-groff)
- [What's the easy way to convert all man pages to html?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264901/whats-the-easy-way-to-convert-all-man-pages-to-html)
- [Convert all Linux man pages to text / html or markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433903/)

## pandoc

Another approach is to use the popular [pandoc tool](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html). This tool can convert manual pages to a wide range of formats.

### Link `x-man-page`

macOS's Terminal.app offers a `x-man-page` URL scheme for pretty printing manual pages. Try opening the link below to see the `ls` man page:

```
x-man-page://ls
```

Comment: Just to verify: On MacOS, `man` doesn't support the `-T` option directly?

Comment: If you use modern Debian/Ubuntu and install package `groff` you can just do `man -Tpdf osascript > osascript.pdf`.

Comment: Good contribution. But does the error only come to me? `cupsfilter: No filter to convert from text/html to application/pdf.`

Comment: @Lano I suspect the error you are seeing is related to the version of macOS you have. Please can you ask this as [a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so others can better help you.

Answer (score 11):

```
man -t yourcommand | open -fa "Preview"
```

where `yourcommand` is the one you want the man page of.

---

```
$ man -t tmutil | open -fa "Preview"
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a *function* I added to my `.bash_profile` file to create a **PDF** of each **BSD** *command* I'd check the *manual page* for:

```
manp () 
{ 
    docDir="$HOME/Documents/BSD Commands"
    [[ ! -d $docDir ]] && mkdir -p "$docDir"
    if [[ ! -f $docDir/$1.pdf ]]; then
        man -t "$1" | pstopdf -i -o "$docDir/$1.pdf"
        open "$docDir/$1.pdf"
    else
        open "$docDir/$1.pdf"
    fi
}
```

So, in **Terminal**, typing e.g. `manp bash` instead of `man bash` a **PDF** gets created, if it hasn't already been, and then opened by the app registered to handle **PDF** documents. The *default* is **Preview**, however on my system it's set to use [**Skim**](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io), as its search functionality is better then **Preview** and as a matter of fact will find the search string when **Preview** just will not.

Note that the first time the *function* is used it will enumerate some fonts in the output in **Terminal**, however this is a one time enumeration of the fonts.

---

As a side note, typing just the *command* name in **Terminal** and then *right-click* on it and select **Open man Page**, displays it in a fully scrollable and searchable **Terminal** window, which is much better then typing e.g. `man bash`.