# How to use the Terminal application to search or print a man page

Tags: terminal, command-line, printing

I often need to search or print a man page. Executing the `man [-a index] name` command invokes a readonly navigable viewer of `name[(index)]`. For example, the command below displays `open(1)`.

```
man  open
```

The command below displays `open(n)`.

```
man  -a  n  open
```

Is there a way to use the Terminal application to involve a viewer where I can search and/or print a man page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing just the *command* name in **Terminal** and then *right-click* on it and select **Open man Page**, displays it in a fully scrollable and searchable **Terminal** window, which is much better then typing e.g. `man bash`. You can also use the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to print the contents.

---

As a side note, here is a *function* I added to my `.bash_profile` file to create a **PDF** of each **BSD** *command* I'd check the *manual page* for:

```
manp () 
{ 
    docDir="$HOME/Documents/BSD Commands"
    [[ ! -d $docDir ]] && mkdir -p "$docDir"
    if [[ ! -f $docDir/$1.pdf ]]; then
        man -t "$1" | pstopdf -i -o "$docDir/$1.pdf"
        open "$docDir/$1.pdf"
    else
        open "$docDir/$1.pdf"
    fi
}
```

So, in **Terminal**, typing e.g. `manp bash` instead of `man bash` a **PDF** gets created, if it hasn't already been, and then opened by the app registered to handle **PDF** documents. The *default* is **Preview**, however on my system it's set to use [**Skim**][1], as its search functionality is better then **Preview** and as a matter of fact will find the search string when **Preview** just will not.

Note that the first time the *function* is used it will enumerate some fonts in the output in **Terminal**, however this is a one time enumeration of the fonts.

Answer (score 4):

```
man -t yourcommand | open -fa "Preview"
```

where `yourcommand` is the one you want the man page of. You can then use any of the normal search functionality in Preview and print the document as a normal PDF.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this should have been posted as an answer to my original question:  [Can man pages be converted to html and/or pdf format?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315272/can-man-pages-be-converted-to-html-and-or-pdf-format)

Comment: @David Okay will move answer and tailor this one to be specific to searching; I never saw that question but seems there's quite a lot of overlap with that question though, and user's posted their answer there too?

Comment: I preferred user3439894 answer to the original question, Right clicking on the text certainly is the easiest to use. The problem was it did not fit the original question. So, I posted this question and asked user3439894 (in a now deleted comment) to post an answer here. I then accepted user3439894's answer.

Comment: @David Thanks for the backstory, that makes more sense!