# Retrieve formatted manual page from command line

Tags: bash

I try to export  the manual page of `grep` to `grep.txt`

```
    $ man grep > ~/desktop/grep.txt
```

It displayed in garbled code:

```
            GREP(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  GREP(1)

            NNAAMMEE
                 ggrreepp, eeggrreepp, ffggrreepp, zzggrreepp, zzeeggrreepp, zzffggrreepp -- file pattern searcher

            SSYYNNOOPPSSIISS
                 ggrreepp [--aabbccddDDEEFFGGHHhhIIiiJJLLllmmnnOOooppqqRRSSssUUVVvvwwxxZZ] [--AA _n_u_m] [--BB _n_u_m] [--CC[_n_u_m]]
```

How to get a formatted manual page from command line?

Comment: Other methods of converting manual pages are given as answers to the questions: ["How to use the Terminal application to search or print a man page"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315297/how-to-use-the-terminal-application-to-search-or-print-a-man-page) and ["Can man pages be converted to html and/or pdf format?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315272/can-man-pages-be-converted-to-html-and-or-pdf-format).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following *example command* to get formatted plain text output for a manual page:

```
man grep | col -bx > ~/Desktop/grep.txt
```

Produces, e.g.:

```
GREP(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  GREP(1)

NAME
     grep, egrep, fgrep, zgrep, zegrep, zfgrep -- file pattern searcher

SYNOPSIS
     grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlmnOopqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
          [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color[=when]]
          [--colour[=when]] [--context[=num]] [--label] [--line-buffered]
          [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

---

To automate the use of e.g. `man grep | col -bx > ~/Desktop/grep.txt` *command* in **Terminal**, so you can just type e.g. `mant grep`, or other *command*, it can be wrapped in a *bash function* placed in your `.bash_profile` *file*.

I normally prefer to have my manual pages in *PDF format* however I've modified the `manp` *bash function* I use in my `.bash_profile` *file* to work for *plain text* as, `mant`.

**For plain text manual pages:**

```
function mant () 
{ 
    mpdir="$HOME/Documents/Manual Pages"
    [[ ! -d $mpdir ]] && mkdir -p "$mpdir"
    if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then
        if [[ ! -f $mpdir/$1.txt ]]; then
            man "$1" | col -bx > "$mpdir/$1.txt"
            open -e "$mpdir/$1.txt"
        else
            open -e "$mpdir/$1.txt"
        fi
    else
        printf '  Error: Missing argument!...\n  Syntax: mant command_name\n  Example: mant man\n'
    fi
}
```

**For PDF manual pages:**

```
function manp () 
{ 
    mpdir="$HOME/Documents/Manual Pages"
    [[ ! -d $mpdir ]] && mkdir -p "$mpdir"
    if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then
        if [[ ! -f $mpdir/$1.pdf ]]; then
            man -t "$1" | pstopdf -i -o "$mpdir/$1.pdf"
            open "$mpdir/$1.pdf"
        else
            open "$mpdir/$1.pdf"
        fi
    else
        printf '  Error: Missing argument!...\n  Syntax: manp command_name\n  Example: manp man\n'
    fi
}
```

To add either or both *bash functions* shown above to your `.bash_profile` *file*, in **Terminal** use the following *command*:

```
nano "$HOME/.bash_profile"
```

Then copy and paste the *function(s)* into the `.bash_profile` *file*, then save the *file* and exit `nano` pressing the following keys:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- <kbd>Y</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Close and reopen the **Terminal** app, not just the window, and you are ready to go.

For the default manual page in **Terminal**, e.g.:

```
man grep
```

For a plain text file manual page, e.g.:

```
mant grep
```

For a PDF file manual page, e.g.:

```
manp grep
```

With the *bash functions*, if a file for the given *command* doesn't already exist, it's created and then opened. If the file of the *command* already exists, it's just opened. This way you can easily access the manual page in the form you'd like while in **Terminal**.

If you want to place the files in a different location, then change the *path* portion of the following line of *code* as appropriate:

```
mpdir="$HOME/Documents/Manual Pages"
```

The rest of the *code* within is tokenized to use `$mpdir` for the location of the *files*.

---

As a side note, if you just want the complete manual page for a given *command*, in a **Terminal** window, which is easily fully scrollable, you can do the following...

Just type the *command name* by itself, then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

This is better then typing e.g. `man grep` and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, because it's fully scrollable and you do not need to navigate using key sequences as defined in the `less` *command* utility used as the pager by `man`.